# How can I install R devtools on Mac?

Tags: r, devtools

I first downloaded the base R package here: https://www.r-project.org/

Then, I downloaded RStudio here: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

I've searched online but there is no good article explaining how to install devtools, the package manager.

Comment: `devtools` is an R package. You can install it like any other R package: open RStudio, type `install.packages("devtools")` in the console, and hit Return. You'll want to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and a [LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) distribution, first.

Comment: One clarification:  `devtools` is not "the package manager".  That's built in to base R.  `devtools` is a contributed package that enhances the package manager and helps with package development.